# Histogram equalization on a color image

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm trying to increase the contrast of an image, by equalizing its histogram and it works great for gray images, and some color images too, but for some it works really weirdly. I equalize every rgb channel separately and i know that you shouldn't do it that way, but i want to confirm whether that's the cause of this problem.

```
 public static void ChangeContrast(Bitmap image, string savePath)
    {
        int width = image.Width;
        int height = image.Height;

        BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
        byte[] newBmp = new byte[bytes];

        double[] probabilityR = new double[256];
        double[] probabilityG = new double[256];
        double[] probabilityB = new double[256];

        byte[,] r = new byte[width, height];
        byte[,] g = new byte[width, height];
        byte[,] b = new byte[width, height];

        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, image.Height * bmpData.Stride);

        //Put green, blue and red values into separate arrays.
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                b[j, i] = rgbValues[k];
                g[j, i] = rgbValues[k + 1];
                r[j, i] = rgbValues[k + 2];
                k += 3;
            }
        }

        //Calculate how many pixels with given intensity are there (sort of a histogram).
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                probabilityR[r[i, j]]++;
                probabilityG[g[i, j]]++;
                probabilityB[b[i, j]]++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            probabilityR[i] /= (width * height);
            probabilityG[i] /= (width * height);
            probabilityB[i] /= (width * height);
        }

        int p = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                double sumR = 0;
                double sumG = 0;
                double sumB = 0;

                for (int x = 0; x < r[i, j]; x++)
                {
                    sumR += probabilityR[x];
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < g[i, j]; x++)
                {
                    sumG += probabilityG[x];
                }
                for (int x = 0; x < b[i, j]; x++)
                {
                    sumB += probabilityB[x];
                }
                newBmp[p++] = (byte)(Math.Floor(255 * sumB));
                newBmp[p++] = (byte)(Math.Floor(255 * sumG));
                newBmp[p++] = (byte)(Math.Floor(255 * sumR));
            }
        }
        Marshal.Copy(newBmp, 0, ptr, bytes);
        image.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        ih.saveImage(image, savePath);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the first set of images looks just fine, but the second lost its red tint.

Comment: "the second lost its red tint" Yes, this is what you asked it to do. If you check the red channel, the histogram for it shows the red channel peaks in the top of the value range. Your code adjusts for that somewhat, and since it works on a per-channel basis the end result is that the colors all essentially normalize. Check the RGB histograms (Paint.NET's Levels Adjustment will show you the channel histograms for easy viewing) before and after.